# Git forcing use of HTTPS

Tags: git, github, ssh, macos-mojave

I created a GitHub repo, then cloned it using SSH:

```
git clone git@github.com:BenReilly/all-the-characters.git
```

I added some files.

```
git add .
git commit -m "some message"
git push
```

this resulted in being prompted for my username and password. Which was kind of weird on its own, but I entered them anyway. Then I get:

```
> remote: Anonymous access to BenReilly/all-the-characters.git denied.
> fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/BenReilly/all-the-characters.git/'
```

HTTPS? What?

```
git remote -v
> origin  https://github.com/BenReilly/all-the-characters.git (fetch)
> origin  https://github.com/BenReilly/all-the-characters.git (push)
```

ugh.

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:BenReilly/all-the-characters.git
git remote -v
> origin  https://github.com/BenReilly/all-the-characters.git (fetch)
> origin  https://github.com/BenReilly/all-the-characters.git (push)
```

is this because it's not in my osxkeychain?

Just to be sure I did `ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/<key id>` and made sure the `~/.ssh/config` file is defined. No change in behavior. I also verified the key is in my GitHub settings.

I am on MacOS Mojave (10.14.1), using Git version 2.17.2.

Why is Git forcing use of HTTPS and ignoring my attempts to set the SSH address?

ETA `.git/config` file

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        ignorecase = true
        precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@github.com:BenReilly/all-the-characters.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

Comment: What does your `.git/config` file look like?

Comment: @lurker  i added it above

Comment: What about `git config --global`? I suspect you've got an [`insteadOf`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-urlltbasegtinsteadOf) entry somewhere.

Comment: @Chris that does appear to be the case. There's a few `insteadOf` entries in there. And the calls all time out now, which I'm 99% certain is the proxy I'm forced to use. I'll have to go to https while on this network. Which has its own problems...

Comment: Okay, great. I'll add an answer now that we know what the problem was.

Comment: @torek I also use ssh addresses without issue on Mojave-d MacOS.

Comment: I know you're trying to help, @torek , but the fact that it works on yours when it doesn't work on mine doesn't provide any useful information

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Git config has an [`insteadOf` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-urlltbasegtinsteadOf):

> `url.<base>.insteadOf`
>
> Any URL that starts with this value will be rewritten to start, instead, with `<base>`. In cases where some site serves a large number of repositories, and serves them with multiple access methods, and some users need to use different access methods, this feature allows people to specify any of the equivalent URLs and have Git automatically rewrite the URL to the best alternative for the particular user, even for a never-before-seen repository on the site. When more than one insteadOf strings match a given URL, the longest match is used.

Basically, if you run something like

```
git config --global url.https://.insteadOf git://
```

you'll get a stanza added to your global Git configuration (`~/.gitconfig` on Unix-like machines) that looks something like

```
[url "https://"]
    insteadOf = git://
```

that will cause Git to automatically translate any remote beginning with `git://` to a remote beginning with `https://`. Look at your global configuration with `git config --global --list` and see if there are any `insteadOf` entries.